# Updating every profile's registry on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, scripting, profile, registry

I have a Windows Server 2003 system that is used for terminal services.  We do not use roaming profiles.  We do not use login scripts.   I have about thirty to fourty accounts that log into this system and as such have local profiles.

One of the software packages that are installed onto this system uses HKCU/Software reg tree for its licensing and so each user has the license key in their local profile.

How can I update all of these different profiles registries in a deterministic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [***Active Setup is no longer advisable***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189243/create-folder-and-file-on-current-user-profile-from-admin-profile/48196886#48196886) ([original source](https://twitter.com/glytzhkof/status/1015273711086206978)).

---

There are several ways to achieve what you want - one clunkier than the other. Terminal servers can be a deployment nightmare - users may not have rights to run **msiexec.exe** and hence MSI self-repair could fail. That's why I generally prefer to use **batch files**, **scripts** or **reg files** for the kind of situation you are facing.

I would use Microsoft's **Active Setup feature**. This is just a fancy name for a feature which allows you to "run something once per profile on login". Here is a good explanation: **http://www.etlengineering.com/installer/activesetup.txt**

Here is a sample active-setup entry for an MSI file (this is the content of a *.reg file):

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\[ProductCode]]
"StubPath"="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe /q /fou [ProductCode]"
```

The "StubPath" command can be anything "runnable", and in your case I would suggest not running msiexec.exe but rather a vbscript via cscript.exe or some other batch mechanism (CMD, REG, Etc...). The reason is what I stated above: msiexec.exe may not be allowed to run for terminal server users. In other words, something like this:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\MyProduct]
"StubPath"="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /k C:\SomeScript.cmd"
```

---

There are other ways to add data to each user's profile such as [**using advertised MSI shortcuts and self-repair**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1011.htm), but I wouldn't recommend that for terminal servers. See [**this serverfault.com answer**](https://serverfault.com/a/276516/20599) for information on problems with the use of MSI files for registry settings.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the registry hive programatically, change the keys, then close the hive. Alternatively, you could use PSExec/runas to run the "update the keys" script as *that user*, which also solves the "edit HKCU" problem

Comment: How do you mount all the hive's programatically?   I haven't found out how to do that yet.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this - you have no business updating any user profiles "out of context" like this. Side effects are likely and consequences unpredictable.