# How to create nested folder in AppData

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm trying to create an installer that installs my `DApp` into ethereum client.

To do so I just have to copy my files into `%appdata%\Parity\Ethereum\dapps\mydappname`. So I have this markup which creates a folder in `%appdata%\mydappname`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="MyDapp" Language="1049" Version="1.0.0.0" 
             Manufacturer="Orbita" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE" Codepage="1251">

      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
      <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyDapp" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
          <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Fairs" />
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
          <Component Id="dapp" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
            <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLFOLDER" On="uninstall" />
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" 
                           Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
            <File Id="chain.json" Source="..\..\..\..\config\chain.json"/>
          </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

However, when I change structure to be nested:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="Parity" Name="Parity">
          <Directory Id="Ethereum" Name="Ethereum">
            <Directory Id="dapps" Name="dapps">
              <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Fairs" />
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

I get `ICE64`s:

```
ICE64: The directory Parity is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
ICE64: The directory Ethereum is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
ICE64: The directory dapps is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
```

What's wrong with markup? I tried change `RemoveDirectory` to

```
<RemoveFolder Id="Parity" On="uninstall" />
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Per-User vs Per-Machine***: Installing to per-user folders (user profile) is generally not recommended for many reasons. Is installing to a per-machine path out of the question? Does your application need to run from a per-user folder?

---

***ICE64***: It looks like you have omitted the `Directory attribute` in your `RemoveFolder element`.

It is required in your case (since the `Directory attribute` defaults to the hosting components installation directory otherwise - which is incorrect in this case).

---

To resolve your validation error you should be able to do something like this:

*Change this*:

```
<RemoveFolder Id="Parity" On="uninstall" />
```

*To this*:

```
<RemoveFolder Id="Parity" Directory="Parity" On="uninstall" />
```

Do this for all folders that exist in the user profile.

---

Here is a larger WiX blurb:

```
<Component Feature="MyFeature" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">

    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Test"
                   Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>

    <File Source="TestFile.txt" />

    <RemoveFolder Id="Parity" Directory="Parity" On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="Ethereum" Directory="Ethereum" On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="dapps" Directory="dapps" On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" On="uninstall" />

</Component>
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately I need a per-user installation, because i'm building it on top of another installation which is per-user. Maybe I just did it wrong with `perMachne` as I actually need `perUser`.

Comment: OK, per-user stuff is challenging - but as long as it works for your deployment scenario. Per-machine setups can contain per-user data, but then you need to use [**a suitable mechanism**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48196886/129130) to get the user specific files copied to every user's userprofile folders when they log in and / or invoke the product. I will throw in [one more link on userprofile files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45920701/129130). And yes, if you have only per-user files you can set the InstallScope to perUser.