# Place ini config file in %appdata% for all users

Tags: windows, deployment, profile, ini, appdata

I'm trying to install the Greenshot.ini in %appdata% of every user that have been created or will be created. So that the user do not have specify which language to use on first login for all users.

Currently manually copying the ini to existing users before the program start works. I don't know how to copy to new users or users with non-generated home folders. How can this be done on a non-domain desktop and a domain desktop. The non-domain is more important and preferred.

Comment: Don't have time to answer this properly right now, but can you use Active Directory? Maybe [check this](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/y57op/group_policy_preferences_files_vs_ini_files_for/) (follow the Microsoft link in there). I have [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48196886/129130). And [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45920700/129130) (largely irrelevant). The best is if the application has a way to create the file itself on launch based on a template file of some sort. That depends on the application design of course. Not familiar with this app.

Comment: Do you want to enforce the same configuration for all users? Should users be able to change the config? It is quite likely that you can put the ini file in the main installation folder and make it writable for all users and then you have only one instance of the file for every computer. I don't know the software properly to verify. All depends on what you need. Perhaps all users should have their own config?

Comment: Seems a lot more user friendly if the program just writes it on first run. You can still base it on a template in the install folder that's configured during the installation.